# Calling a flow through REST api returns "http body is required" error

Tags: rest-api, visual-workflow, httprequest, post, curl

I'm trying to initiate a flow through the REST api using PHP:

```
$url = "https://myInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/actions/custom/flow/EndCourse_and_Semester_Notification";

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: OAuth myAccessToken",
    "Content-type: application/json",
    "Content-Length: 0"
);

$body = '{}';

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($response;
curl_close($curl);
```

(myInstance replaces my instace and the same goes for the access token)

When i print the response i get the following error message:

> string(118) "[{"message":"The HTTP entity body is required, but this request has no entity body.","errorCode":"JSON_PARSER_ERROR"}]"

Why is this happening? i have an empty body and a size defined.
Also worth mentioning is that i tried doing the same without a body or size defined and then i got an error of:

> "POST requires content-length"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

flow expect input parameters while calling through API so you need to pass blank input array if you are not passing any value. Update your body with following json

```
{
"inputs": [
    {}
 ]
}
```

So your code will look like this

```
$url = "https://myInstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v40.0/actions/custom/flow/EndCourse_and_Semester_Notification";

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: OAuth myAccessToken",
    "Content-type: application/json",
    "Content-Length: 0"
);

$body = '{"inputs":[{}]}';

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
$response = curl_exec($curl);

var_dump($response;
curl_close($curl);
```

[image]

Comment: Tried `$body = '{"inputs":[{}]}';` and i also tried: 
`$uncoded_body = array("inputs" => array());
$body = json_encode($uncoded_body);`
both return the same error...

Comment: have you tested form workbench?

Comment: Tried through workbench right now, set the headers with the content length and the empty inputs array and still the same error.

Comment: @RealGigex match your input with updated answer screenshot or post your workbench screenshot with your question, this is working for me

Comment: YES! it works now! i had a pair of '' surrounding the body declaration in the workbench which caused the issue, and in my code i fixed it by using
`$body = "{\"inputs\":[{}]}";`
instead of
`$body = '{"inputs":[{}]}';`
Thank you!